# JSFiddle does not let me set input value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spinner

I am implementing Jquery Numeric box in one of my page. I have to take numeric input from user which has its min and max value. The problem is that one I set the minimum value and try to input value using keyboard, it automatically displays minimum value without letting me input full value.

For example in the demo:  [Demo Link Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sk3145/Uygt2/156/)

```
max = $this.spinner('option', 'max'),
min = $this.spinner('option', 'min');
```

Min is set to 100 and Max is set to 1000 but if i want to input 500 from keyboard, once I press 5, it will automatically sets its value 100.

Has anyone has same issue?

Comment: Can you give link of fiddle

Comment: Was editing my question, u were fast asking for link... ;)

Comment: This is because keydown reacts on when a key is pressed. So, it sees 5 as keydown, and thinks, "Hey, the minimum is 100 and you're inputting 5!". You can use "blur" instead, but this means you need to lose focus on the input field first, before it updates. **Edit:** Apperently you're using input aswell, basically, every key pressed with on('input') counts as a key press, so use blur so it waits for the user to lose focus of the inputfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the `.on('input'...)` in your code to `.on('blur'...)`, and change the value only after i know the user "finished" entering his input, and not before that like in your example.

Comment: But what if I don't have any .on('blur'...) function. In another i have only $('#spinner_example').spinner({
    min: 100,
    max: 1000,
    step: 1
});

Comment: So just ad to this the .on('blur', function()...) part. the .spinner() method can be chained to any other jQuery method.

Comment: Got my required output... :)

Answer (score 3):

I made some changes in your code  try this  [plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/kaiser07/Uygt2/157/):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" value="0" >
```

**JS:**

```
$("input").spinner({
    max: 1000,
    min: 100
}).on('blur', function () {
    if ($(this).data('onInputPrevented')) return;
    var val = this.value,

        $this = $(this),
        max = $this.spinner('option', 'max'),
        min = $this.spinner('option', 'min');

        // only allow numbers
       $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));

    // check input value
        if(val< 100 ){
            console.log(val.toString().length)
           if(val.toString().length == 1)
            $("input").val(val + 0 + 0);
            if(val.toString().length == 2)
                $("input").val(val + 0);


        }

});
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but thumbs up for your support... :)